# Custom Datepicker Label in swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4

I have a collectionview in which a label is used in header.i want to show a datepicker when this label is clicked.a custom date picker label has been created however i don't know how to use this datepicker label in my controller as currently datepicker is not shown when click to date header label.

```
class DatePickerLabel: UILabel {

private let _inputView: UIView? = {
    let picker = UIDatePicker()
    return picker
}()

private let _inputAccessoryToolbar: UIToolbar = {
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolBar.isTranslucent = true
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    return toolBar
}()

override var inputView: UIView? {
    return _inputView
}

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
    return _inputAccessoryToolbar
}

required init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(doneClick))
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    _inputAccessoryToolbar.setItems([ spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)

    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(launchPicker))
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}



override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
    return true
}

@objc private func launchPicker() {
    becomeFirstResponder()
}

@objc private func doneClick() {
    resignFirstResponder()
}
}
```

Custom header class :-

```
class DetailHeader : UICollectionReusableView
{

@IBOutlet weak var paramName : UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var paramDate : DatePickerLabel!

}
```

My viewController code -

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader){
    let sectionHeader = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerreuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DetailHeader
    sectionHeader.paramName.text = selectedParam?.name
        sectionHeader.paramDate.text = dateToString(date: stringToDate(strdate: (detailList?.date)!))
        sectionHeader.paramDate = DatePickerLabel()
    return sectionHeader
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not enabled the user interaction in your `DatePickerLabel`. Default value of `isUserInteractionEnabled` is `false`. So override it in your `DatePickerLabel`

```
override var isUserInteractionEnabled: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Also your `init` is never called. Because in the case of Nib/Storyboard, `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called. Move your code from init to `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and it will start working.

Comment: I tried to make DatePickerLabel UserInteractionEnabled using xcode as well as through code in constructor by self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true but not working. Actually i am getting paramDate nil so something is missing while initialising DatePickerLabel in controller.

Comment: I see. Does your app crash? because `paramDate` is not optional, so it must crash if it's nil. And what about the `paramName`? is it also nil?

Comment: No it doesn't crash but on click of label datePicker doesn't appear.do i need to add some delegate in viewcontroller or something else ?.param name is fine, it shows value it intends for.

Comment: But when i removed sectionHeader.paramDate = DatePickerLabel() from viewcontroller paramDate is not null.

Comment: I ran your code and I've found the problem. Your `init` is never called. Because in the case of Nib/Storyboard, `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called. Move your code from `init` to `init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` and it will start working.

Comment: And don't forget about setting `isUserInteractionEnabled` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan as suggested moving code inside init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) worked.